# php store a variable in an array?

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I am just a newbie in php. So this question may be sound like childish. But I really want to know this.I saw in a php file one php code line was like this

`$taxonomies = array();`

Here it is looking like taxonomies is the variable stored in an array if I am not wrong. So can someone clear me what is the purpose of doing this?How the variable is stored in an array Any live example or any link will really clear my doubt.

Comment: It means that $taxonomies variable IS array.

Comment: Sorry, but this question is clearly too localized. Please get yourself an [introductory tutorial about PHP](http://phpmaster.com/category/php-tutorials/beginner/) and also read http://php.net/variables

Answer (score 2):

This just defines that this variable is an array.

Answer (score 2):

It declares `$taxonomies` as an empty [array with no elements](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php). You can use this to declare an array you don't know its element beforehand

```
$taxonomies = array(); 

echo count($taxonomies); //outputs 0 - meaning no elements
```

Start adding elements to the array

```
$taxonomies[] = "John";  //puts John in positon 0

$taxonomies['species'] = 'Pisces';  //associative array

$taxonomies[10] = 'Arachnida';

echo count($taxonomies); //outputs 3 - no longer empty
```

Answer (score 2):

The variable `$taxonomies` does not become stored in the array after your example snippet, `$taxonomies` literally becomes an array.

`array ()` is used to form an empty array, which is exactly what `$taxonomies` is after your statement.

---

To add elements to your new array you could either use the empty square-bracket trick (`$taxonomies[] = "new element";`) or `array_push` (among other functions).

Answer (score 1):

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

`$taxonomies` is set to a blank array

`$taxonomies[0] = "foo"` would set index 0 to `foo`

PHP also supports associative arrays so you could also do

`$taxonomies["name"] = "John"`

In PHP arrays are actually ordered maps, so you don't need to setup and initial size.

Answer (score 0):

As other people posted, it says the variable is array, which in turn will surpress warnings, when you will use $taxonomies forexample in foreach. Everytime when you can get an empty value out of some function etc and later you work with that variable as with an array, always do this check:

```
if(empty($taxonomies))$taxonomies = array();
```

Now you can write

```
foreach ($taxonomies as $value)
```

without having fear of PHP warnings